# Read next line in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to search for a string in a text file, and if that string is found, output the next line.

I've looked at some similar questions on here but couldn't get anything from them to help me.

This is the program I have made. I have made it solely to solve this specific problem and so it's also probably not perfect in many other ways.

```
def searcher():
    print("Please enter the term you would like the definition for")
    find = input()
    with open ('glossaryterms.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if find in line:
                print(line)
```

So the text file will be made up of the term and then the definition below it.

For example:

> Python
>   A programming language I am using

If the user searches for the term `Python`, the program should output the definition.

I have tried different combinations of print (line+1) etc. but no luck so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

your code is handling each line as a term, in the code below f is an iterator so you can use next to move it to the next element:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        nextLine = next(f)
        if 'A' == line.strip():
            print nextLine
```

Comment: It's preferable to use the `next()` function for this, rather than call the `iterator.next()` method.

Comment: Doesn't work if the search string is not on a line that's a multiple of two - every odd line is skipped. Moving the next into the print statement resolves this but creates another issue that if it is again found in that line, the next line will not be printed

Comment: @meiamsome : "So the text file will be made up of the term and then the definition below it."

Comment: @PawełKordowski Ah, yep, probably fine then! hah

Comment: It works, thanks. Not sure I understand why just yet but will try to dismantle it to help my understanding. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

If your filesize is small, then you may simply read the file by using [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) which returns a list of strings each delimited by `\n` character, and then find the index of the selected word, and the print the item at *position + 1* in the given list.

This can be done as:

```
def searcher():
    print("Please enter the term you would like the definition for")
    find = input()

    with open("glossaryterms.txt", "r") as f:       
        words = list(map(str.strip, f.readlines()))
        try: 
            print(words[words.index(find) + 1])
        except:
            print("Sorry the word is not found.")
```

Comment: An example would be more better :)

Comment: Thanks. Could you please give me an example of this in code as I can't really translate what you're saying in to working lines?

Comment: @user1480135: Check [the document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines). `file.readlines()` read all lines of the file and put the lines into a list.

Comment: Thanks @KevinGuan for the link :) it's worth checking out.

Comment: Not sure your example works per the original spec (i.e. that the find string has to be in the line, not that it is the line, e.g. searching for Py in the example), relatively simple to fix though, I guess!

Comment: As per the problem statement : *I am trying to figure out how to search for a string in a text file*, So I guess the OP wants to query the whole string.

Comment: yes, but your code does not differ between terms and definitions

Comment: The `index()` returns the first occurrence of the given word if any.

Comment: Tried this but it gives me the error "'map' object has no attribute 'index'"

Comment: Are you using Python 3 @user1480135

Comment: I am using Using 3.4.1

Comment: wrong: list.index(x)
Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item. I've edited the solution

Answer (score 2):

You could try it Quick and dirty with a flag.

```
with open ('glossaryterms.txt', 'r') as file:
  for line in file:
    if found:
        print (line)
        found = False
    if find in line:
        found = True
```

It's just important to have the "if found:" before setting the flag. So if you found your search term next iteration/line will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

In my mind, the easiest way would be to cache the last line. This means that on any iteration you would have the previous line, and you'd check on that - keeping the loop relatively similar

For example:

```
def searcher():
    last_line = ""
    print("Please enter the term you would like the definition for")
    find = input()
    with open ('glossaryterms.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if find in last_line:
                print(line)
            last_line = line
```

Comment: Theoretically I would have thought that this would work, but for some reason it just does nothing after the search term is entered

Comment: @user1480135 Works fine for me, if you're using python 2 it should be raw_input, perhaps that's the issue?